# JLabel.setVisible(false) make other components' position change

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I meet a relayout problem that is in my swing application I add four components (two JLabels, one JTextField and one table, each occupies one row) to a panel by using GridBagLayout, for some logic, I need to make one label visible true or false based on some conditions, but when I invoke setVisible(false) the components below this label will come up a little and when I invoke setVisible(true) they come down a little which makes the GUI flashing. Are there any methods which can make other components stick on the panel? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of setting the label visible or not, you could just change the text between the default and  `""`.  The Label would still stack the same height but no text would be visible.

Comment: It seems setText("") can't work but setText(" ") do. Thanks, jzd.

Comment: yes, setText(" ") does the trick indeed.

Answer (score 1):

How about TableLayout with fixed columns and rows?